# trying to remove array item from second level

Tags: php

ive tried to look this up but i have not found an array like mine. nor has anything ive tried worked, now im getting an eror for the umtenth time.

ive comment the error at 103/104
i need to at one point get this from a serialized array hence the converting (sorry)
im trying to make a function that can look for what needs to be removed.

note: i also need to add a complete record too, as im not getting how to do that in arrays either but i should maybe ask that as another questions.

everything i look up for arrays i do not find exactly what i have it has [0] => as the top array, and when i try its example it does not seam to be the same array i have.
hence asking question here.

thank you for any help here's my php code below

```
<?php
    // version:
$testarray =    
Array(
        "heading" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Salads',
            "1" => 'Salads',
            "2" => 'Pasta',
        ),

        "special" => Array
        (
            "0" => '',
            "1" => '',
            "2" => '',
        ),

        "item" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Small Green',
            "1" => 'Regular Caesar',
            "2" => 'Baked Lasagna',
        ),

        "description" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Grape tomatoes, onions, green peppers and cucumbers on the bed of crisp lettuce.',
            "1" => 'Classic recipe with romaine lettuce and croutons',
            "2" => 'With meat sauce, tomato vegetarian sauce or Alfredo sauce',
        ),

        "price" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'See Desc',
            "1" => '$5.99',
            "2" => '$9.69',
        ),

        "notes" => Array
        (
            "0" => 'Available in Small ($2.99), Regular ($5.99)',
            "1" => '',
            "2" => '',
        ),

        "submit_val" => 'Submit'
    );

// does not work errors at this - Using $this when not in object context in
/*
function recursion($array0) {
    foreach ($array0 as $key0 => $value0) {
    echo $value0;
    if (is_array($value0))
        $this->recursion($value0);
    }
}
echo "recursion array<br>";
echo recursion($testarray);
*/


echo "testarray";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($testarray);
echo "</pre>";  
echo "<hr>";
$removed_array = removeItem(serialize($testarray), '"Submit"'); 
echo "removed array";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($removed_array);
echo "</pre>";  

// need to test this too for if it works or not need to add complete set ie
// header='pasta', special='',item = 'Spaghetti with Meatballs', descriotion = 'Spaghetti with  4 Meatballs', price='$9.99',notes=''
// need to be able to add above line to array [3] line
    function addItem($serializedArray, $item) 
{
   $a = unserialize($serializedArray);
   $a[] = $item;
   return serialize($a);
}

// trying to remove [submit_val] => Submit
global $serializedArray;
$serializedArray = array();
function removeItem($serializedArray, $remove){
    echo "passed array";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($serializedArray); 
echo "</pre>";  
   $a = unserialize($serializedArray);
 echo "search for remove: ".$remove."<br>";
    foreach($a as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br>';
    // get error here as Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for next line
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
          echo $key2 . ' = ' . $value2 . '<br>';    
          if ($value2 == $remove) {
          echo "at value now ".$value2;     
          echo "search for remove: ".$remove;
      unset($a[$key2]);
      echo "unset: ". $a[$key2];
      }// if
      else {
      //echo "didnt find: ".$remove."<br>";
      }// if

    } //for each inner key2

    } // ofr each outer key
    return serialize($a);
}   // function
?>
```

edit: great i got answers to my testing of recursions, but the problem i having removing an item from the array is farther down im trying to remove "submit_val" => 'Submit' with no luck (this is the post question) sorry i was not clear

in case anyones interest taken from suggestions below

```
works now thank you
/**/
function recursion($array0) {
    foreach ($array0 as $key0 => $value0) {
    echo $value0;
    if (is_array($value0))
      return  recursion($value0);
    }
}
echo "recursion array<br>";
echo '<pre>';
echo recursion($testarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: i revised the post question  thank you for answers yes i would like to know the recursion answer too - and how to return it..again thanks and sorry for the confusions, please see edit note at bottom of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$this` is throwing an error, because your using it out of an object.. An acceptable usage of `$this` will be:

```
class Test { 
 function recursion($array0) {
    foreach ($array0 as $key0 => $value0) {
    echo $value0;
    if (is_array($value0))
        $this->recursion($value0);
    }
  }

}
```

Your function should be:

```
function recursion($array0) {
    foreach ($array0 as $key0 => $value0) {
    echo $value0;
    if (is_array($value0))
        recursion($value0);
    }
}
```

Remove the `$this` should resolve the error.

Comment: i revised my question - see edit note at bottom please -  thank you for answer

Comment: i excepted this and asked question. thanks for the help in that area

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursion($array0) {
    foreach ($array0 as $key0 => $value0) {
    echo $value0;
    if (is_array($value0))
        recursion($value0);
    }
}
```

Though don't you want to return anything from the function?